# How do I escape this (salt) string inside XML?

Tags: xml, azure, escaping

I am about to deploy my service on Windows Azure when I get this error:

> Error: The provided configuration file contains XML that could not be parsed. '$' is an unexpected token. The expected token is ';'. Line 14, position 99.

I have the following value inside my ServiceConfiguration.cscfg file

```
<Setting name="AUTH_KEY" value="6v2^mG+$VN`P_9e9KVWkn)}8 Vtdqj?kB7l&kgVcR8i[P/h1dWp9q!(0~ eZ[xTk" />
```

Is there a way to escape the whole string?

Alternatively can I just escape the culprit "$"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A comprehensive list of XML escape characters can be found on WikiPedia at

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Comment: Ben, you seem to be everywhere. It's me your favourite student. ;)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with the `$`. It is with the `&` in the value of the `value` attribute:

```
"6v2^mG+$VN`P_9e9KVWkn)}8 Vtdqj?kB7l&kgVcR8i[P/h1dWp9q!(0~ eZ[xTk"
```

Escape it to a `&amp;` and you should be fine:

```
"6v2^mG+$VN`P_9e9KVWkn)}8 Vtdqj?kB7l&amp;kgVcR8i[P/h1dWp9q!(0~ eZ[xTk"
```

Comment: +1 Thanks. that was the ampersand. But there was also < >, which I have now figured out with Ben's link. Many Thanks

Comment: @Kave - I'd have said something about those, but you didn't include them in your code.

Comment: You are right. I wished I could tick two answers as correct. :(  I gave you another +1 on this. Hope that compensates a bit. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to avoid issues around XML encoding in the .csfg file is if you edit the value through the properties of the role (either double click it, or right click -> properties).  When you change values in the settings tab it deals with encoding for you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't the "$". XMLSpy says:

```
File Untitled1.xml is not well-formed.
Character '[' is grammatically unexpected
    Reason: one of the following is expected (see below)
        ';'
    Details
        XML production: Production 'EntityRef' not satisfied
```

You need to escape the "`&`" as "`&amp;`".